# Integrating servicenow with onedrive.while try to get OAuth token for onedrive getting invalid scope error

Tags: servicenow, servicenow-rest-api

I did the Microsoft app registration to get the client id and secret key.

Then I created the OAUth application registry in ServiceNow. Then I try to get the OneDrive access token in ServiceNow it throws me a invalid scope error.

How could I go about this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. But I think your question is still not answerable. **You** should [edit] your question now, to add missing details (see [mcve] ). Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Comment: I agree with @GhostCat, but do have something that **may** help.

In this video Josh Nerius and Dave Slusher connect to Office365 (I assume, same for One Drive) Follow their direction.  It's not an answer, but a direction.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4_Tu3AAerkA